# How to create annotation on filtered data in Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm, django-aggregation

I have the following models:

```
class ApiUser(models.Model):
    apikey = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)


class ExtMethodCall(models.Model):
    apiuser = models.ForeignKey(ApiUser)
    method  = models.CharField(max_length=100) #method name
    units   = models.PositiveIntegerField()    #how many units method call cost
    created_dt = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

For report, i need to get all users who made any call today and total cost of all calls for each user.

In SQL, that would be something like:

```
SELECT apiuser.*, q1.total_cost
FROM apiuser INNER JOIN (
    SELECT apiuser_id, sum(units) as total_cost
    FROM extmethodcall
    WHERE create_dt = curdate()
    GROUP by apiuser_id
) USING apiuser_id
```

So far, i have found the following solution:

```
models.ExtMethodCall.objects.filter(created_dt=datetime.date.today()).values('apiuser').annotate(Sum('units'))
```

which returns me `apiuser_id` and `units__sum`.

Is there any more intelligent solution?

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you've given?

Comment: it is not obvious as for me. actually i googled it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any more intelligent solution?

No this is the most natural solution, Django ORM will "tanslate"

`.annotate(Sum('units'))`

into SQL

`SELECT ... sum(units) as units__sum`